# What are good ways to encode order between records of a relational table

Tags: database-design, relational-database, relational-modelling

For example, when an issue tracker offers the functionality to users to keep a prioritized backlog of tasks and used a relational database for persisting this information, what are effective ways to encode this information?

Of course one could introduce an integral field `priority` (possibly unique) and sort entries according to that priority field, but this might not be a good solution when considering that the priorities might have to be reordered by the user. I wonder if there is a body of work on this or good practices.

Comment: Are you looking for a doubly linked list? First Stack Overflow search result: [loading a double linked list from a sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/732436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is. If you just want a simple ordering, then you can just an integer column for `order`, or `priority`, etc. But if you want *columns* for priority, like a kanban board, you might encode that differently by having for example an M to N mapping of `issues` and `columns`. In that case, you can also have an `order` or `priority` for your `issue`, so that in can be ordered correctly in the column.

Reordering by the user is a trivial problem. You would simply keep track of the *original* order of the issue  (i.e. the integer value `order`); once you know the *updated*/*new* order, it’s some basic math to get all issues for that column and update their orders as well. For example, you have these 3 issues in the column named “TODO”:

- “Fix database bug” - `order = 1`
- “Fix UI bug” - `order = 2`
- “Implement feature” - `order = 3`

you could move “Implement feature” to the top and adjust the order values for the other issues in that column to:

- “Implement feature” - `order = 1`
- “Fix database bug” - `order = 2`
- “Fix UI bug” - `order = 3`

So, to answer the root question, *it depends on your use case*!

But all in all I think most people just use a simple integer column and some basic order-update logic when things get moved around. **Note** that this requires 1 database record update for every item that needs to have its order adjusted (in the above example, 3 records are updated). However, this shouldn’t be an issue for most relational databases as you could (and *should*) wrap those updates in a transaction.

Comment: Agree that its normally just a numeric column - note that doesn't need to be exposed at the UI level.  You can provide mechanisms that order (via drag and drop for example) and the UI code (or server code) can handle the renumbering.